# Drop shadow in Winforms Controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, drop-shadow

is there a way to add a drop shadow to controls?

are there any controls out there with this feature?

Comment: what do I do now? none of the answers really solved the Issue...

Comment: Simon's suggestion below even works for non-rectangular shaped forms (through regions), at least on Windows 7.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This question has been around for 6 years and needs an answer. I hope that anyone who needs to do this can extrapolate an answer for any control set from my solution. I had a panel and wanted to draw a drop shadow underneath every child control - in this instance one or more panels (but the solution should hold good for other control types with some minor code changes).

As the drop shadow for a control has to be drawn on the surface of that control's container we start by adding a function to the container's Paint() event.

```
Container.Paint += dropShadow;
```

dropShadow() looks like this:

```
    private void dropShadow(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Panel panel = (Panel)sender;
        Color[] shadow = new Color[3];
        shadow[0] = Color.FromArgb(181, 181, 181);
        shadow[1] = Color.FromArgb(195, 195, 195);
        shadow[2] = Color.FromArgb(211, 211, 211);
        Pen pen = new Pen(shadow[0]);
        using (pen)
        {
            foreach (Panel p in panel.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
            {
                Point pt = p.Location;
                pt.Y += p.Height;
                for (var sp = 0; sp < 3; sp++)
                {
                    pen.Color = shadow[sp];
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, pt.X, pt.Y, pt.X + p.Width - 1, pt.Y);
                    pt.Y++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Clearly you can pick a different control type from the container's collection and you can vary the colour and depth of the shadow with some minor tweaks.

Comment: I did test it and it did work and I did change it... changed your DrawLine and added a second one... e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, pt.X + sp, pt.Y, pt.X + p.Width - 1 + sp, pt.Y); e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, p.Right + sp, p.Top + sp, p.Right + sp, p.Bottom + sp); it looks like this: http://imgur.com/MfaR39s

Comment: Hi, nice tweak - I only applied the bottom shadow as I was emulating Material Design (cards in particular) but I think that the combination should satisfy anyone looking for a solution.

Answer (score 34):

You have to overwrite the `CreateParams`property like this:

```
private const int CS_DROPSHADOW = 0x00020000;
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        // add the drop shadow flag for automatically drawing
        // a drop shadow around the form
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ClassStyle |= CS_DROPSHADOW;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Is there a complete list of other neat tricks like this?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: LOL - I love your nick

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: What kind of tricks do you think about?

Comment: @Simon Linder: this works great for Forms.. any ideas on applying this to controls?

Comment: @Luiscencio: I'm not sure but as this property applies to a lot of standard controls (as e.g. Button), the CS_DROPSHADOW flag may also apply to them. Check the MSDN for classes that implement the CreateParams property.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: CS_DROPSHADOW is a class style. There are also others, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633574(VS.85).aspx and WinUser.h from you SDK installation path.

Comment: Talk about leaky abstractions!

Comment: @Simon Linder: I override the CreateParams property and it works fine with my application but it slows the Shadowed form while moving, can you please help me to find out the reason why it is happening ?

Comment: @SharpUrBrain: Try to set `this.DoubleBuffered = true;` This should help.

Comment: @Simon Linder: In Loaded() event I am using this but still not fixed :(

Comment: @SharpUrBrain: Normally you wouldn't do that in the Loaded() event but in the constructor respectively in `InitializeComponents()`. You could also try adding the following in the constructor: `SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true); UpdateStyles();`

Comment: In your solution , when its a Dialog Window , when u click outside of it and then back in , Shadow is lost !

Comment: @Billy Xd  Override OnActivated and add this: `var cp = this.CreateParams;
base.OnActivated(e); SetClassLongPtr(this.Handle, -26, (IntPtr)(cp.ClassStyle | CS_DROPSHADOW)); this.Invalidate(false);`  `-26` is [`GCL_STYLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclasslongptrw)

Answer (score 8):

The top answer does in fact generate a shadow, but I personally wasn't satisfied with it for a few reasons:

- It only works for rectangles (granted, WinForms controls are all rectangles, but we might want to use this in other cases)
- More importantly: It's not smooth. It doesn't look as natural as other shadows in other programs look.
- Finally, it's slightly annoying to configure.

So, because of all these things, I ended up writing my own for my project and I thought I'd share it here:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Control> shadowControls = new List<Control>();
    Bitmap shadowBmp = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        shadowControls.Add(panel1);
        this.Refresh();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (shadowBmp == null || shadowBmp.Size != this.Size)
        {
            shadowBmp?.Dispose();
            shadowBmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        }
        foreach (Control control in shadowControls)
        {
            using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                gp.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(control.Location.X, control.Location.Y, control.Size.Width, control.Size.Height));
                DrawShadowSmooth(gp, 100, 60, shadowBmp);
            }
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(shadowBmp, new Point(0, 0));
        }
    }
    private static void DrawShadowSmooth(GraphicsPath gp, int intensity, int radius, Bitmap dest)
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(dest))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
            g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            double alpha = 0;
            double astep = 0;
            double astepstep = (double)intensity / radius / (radius / 2D);
            for (int thickness = radius; thickness > 0; thickness--)
            {
                using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.FromArgb((int)alpha, 0, 0, 0), thickness))
                {
                    p.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round;
                    g.DrawPath(p, gp);
                }
                alpha += astep;
                astep += astepstep;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this implementation, all Controls added to the `shadowControls` will be painted with a smooth shadow. You should be able to implement this for non-rectangular shapes because the main function to generate the shadows takes a `GraphicsPath`. Please note that it's important you draw the shadow to another bitmap before drawing it to the form because the main function requires a compositing mode of `SourceCopy` to work, which means if you don't draw it to another surface first anything behind the shadow will be completely replaced and the transparency aspect is useless. I'm on a roll of answering 10-year-old questions, but hopefully, this helps someone!

Comment: Could this be applied to a single control's Paint such as a Panel instead of applying to the Paint of the parent control ? Not sure if it was by design but applying to the parent Paint is the only way I can get it to work... This is the only good solution I've found so far, thank you.

Comment: When I try this in VB.NET, everything runs and executes but I never see any shadow - any ideas?

Comment: For the thickness loop, won't `alpha` be `0` for the first two cycles? `alpha` starts at zero and is only changed after the drawing in the loop, then it has `astep` added, but that's also zero on the first loop.

Answer (score 2):

There is in WPF if you can stretch to using that instead, I don't believe there is an alternative in Windows Forms due to the limited capabilities of GDI+.

Comment: he could probably do it if he wrote custom controls and added a shadow effect in an overridden Paint method.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - yeah, that's what that article in my post is doing.  It's still a horrible, horrible way to do a relatively simple thing!

Comment: The article you mentioned does not exists anymore

Comment: After the edit this answer doesn't really give much information. I think the originally linked article [has been moved here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19258/Transparent-drop-shadow-in-C-GDI).

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to put your control in a table layout with these properties:

- 3 columns (5px, 100%, 5px)
- 3 rows (5px, 100%, 5px)
- Your control

  - top left corner (0,0)
  - columnSpan = 2 and rowSpan = 2
  - 0 margin
  - Dock set to fill
- Add a panel

  - set with your shadow color as the background
  - row = 1, column = 3
  - 0 margin
  - Dock set to fill
- Add another panel

  - set with your shadow color as the background
  - row = 3, column = 1, columnSpan = 2
  - 0 margin
  - Dock set to fill

This will give you flexibility over sizing by sizing the outer columns and rows. Here is a quick sketch to visualize what the table layout would look like in the designer:

[Table Layout Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEuUY.png)

[Table Layout Sketch 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KEec.png)

Actual screenshot of the end result in an application:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdtFB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a controversial opinion, you do it without code.
Set your main panel Border Style to Fixed Single.
Create 3 panels below it, each 1 pixel larger in every direction.
Each of the 3 panels is of a lighter shade of gray.
Not perfect but cheap and easy.

[panel with pseudo-shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkk3a.png)