# Shadow to windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, background-image, transparent

I am working in C# Windows Forms Application
I want to make shadow of my form, so I have taken a image having shadow and set it as Form's Background image and also set `TransparentKey` to Form's BackColor i.e. `Control Color`, so that it will transparent the area which contains Control color and `FormBorderStyle` to `None`.

My problem is that I am not getting the shadow transparent, it is of Control Color.

**Updated:** I also want to change shape of my form

[image: Form Image]

Comment: I updated my answer with the means to change the shape of a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this technique instead; it worked beautifully for me.
[Drop shadow in Winforms Controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463519/drop-shadow-in-winforms-controls)

Update:
Changing the shape of a form is easier than you'd think.
Follow this tutorial:  http://www.codegod.de/WebAppCodeGod/creating-custom-shapes-for-forms-in-windows-forms-AID377.aspx

Comment: That is awesome!  I had no idea...  And to think, I've been copying the pixels behind me this whole time.

Comment: Great Answer, but I also want to change shape as in Updated Question

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It still draws semi-gray (transparency key) instead of semi-transparent. How can I fix this?