# Winforms border style

Tags: vb.net, winforms, formborderstyle

I am trying to make a form with a border like the border on the Windows Vista volume control. The form would need to be resizeable as well.

[image]

Thanks, giodamelio

To be a little more clear about what I am looking for.
Here is a form with the **ControlBox** property set to false.

[image]

Here is a rough Photoshop of what I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: Check accepted answer at [Drop shadow in Winforms Controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463519/drop-shadow-in-winforms-controls)

Comment: @Javed Akram Though that is interesting and my play a role in the final answer, it is not the complete picture.

Comment: You can use Spy++ to see what styles are applied to the mixer popup, then try setting those same styles in your CreateParams

Comment: Ill try that when I have access to my dev machine tomorro.

Comment: Unfortunately, my dev machine is having a boatload of issues and has some nasty rootkit on it I think. I reinstalled the os and it stuck! Must have hid itself on my linux drive! Needless to say, my work on this will be on hold till I can get this fixed. That may take a few days cause of school. :(

Comment: @boo turns out spy++ doesn't ship with VS Express. If Someone wouldn't mind posting a screenshot of the output here that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the forms `.Controlbox=False`
Set the forms `.Text=""`

Done.

Comment: I can believe I did not think of `setting Text=""`. If this is it, I'm going to kick myself. As my comment above says it might be a few days till I can put this to the test.

Comment: Do not kick yourself to hard. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable in your Projectsettigs "enable XP-Visual Style".
If you launch your application now, you should have the default borderstyle of the launched OS

Comment: I mean get rid of the bar of the top and the maximize, minimize and close buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [`FormBorderStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx) to [`None` or `Fixed(3D|Single)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41.aspx) and work from there, perhaps.

Alternatively, setting the [`ControlBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.controlbox.aspx) to `False` should also have the effect of hiding the title bar. However, beware that the form won’t update automatically:

> If you set ControlBox to false, and also set the Location property, the Size property of Form will not update to reflect that the non-client area of the form has been hidden. **To fix this problem, put the code which alters the Location property to the HandleCreated event.**

Comment: Even after doing that, the topbar(taskbar?) stays.

Comment: @giodamelio It’s been some time since I’ve used WinForms (before Vista) but at least with `None` as the border style there should be no non-client area at all, hence no title bar.

Comment: True, but then I have the issue of drawing the border and shadow on again.

Comment: @giodamelio See my added remark concerning the `ControlBox` property.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Setting the `Controlbox` property to `False` removes the maximize, minimize and close buttons but does not actually remove the topbar itself. My second picture is with `ControlBox=False`, As you can see, the topbar remains.

Comment: @giodamelio That’s why I added the quote from MSDN. Setting `ControlBox` to `False` *should* remove the title bar. If that’s not happening the reason is that the resizing event has not been fired. You may need to set the property in the `HandleCreated` event to get the desired effect.

Comment: The part `To fix this problem, put the code which alters the Location property to the HandleCreated event.1` confuses me. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @giodamelio Admittedly, this is confusing. I don’t have Windows so I can’t experiment (it works under Mono!). I take that to mean that you need to re-set the size of the form after disabling the `ControlBox` so that the form’s non-client are vanishes.

Comment: Using this code, I reset the size in the Form_HandleCreate, the results are the same. `Private Sub Form1_HandleCreated(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.HandleCreated
        Me.Size = New Size(300, 300)
    End Sub`

Comment: I am am thinking maybe overriding the onPaint sub and drawing custom borders.

Answer (score 0):

One way achieve this by following steps:

- Set `FormBorderStyle` of your `Form` to `None`.
- Take a `PictureBox`, set its `Dock` Property to `Fill`.
- Take a image containing Border, and set this `Image` to the PictureBox.

Comment: That is a cool trick, and way more out of the box then I was thinking.  Here(http://gyazo.com/01a132bd42e4bce1eb49780aece50619.png) is a screenshot of it in action. The form would not be resizeable though, which I would need.

Comment: @giodamelio, by setting `FormBorderStyle` to **NONE**, form will not be resizable.

Comment: I overlooked that fact. That is another reason that this solution will not work for me.

Comment: If you want to resize the form by mouse and move too, I will give you a link shortly.....

Comment: See [Drag borderless windows form by mouse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767831/drag-borderless-windows-form-by-mouse)