# How do I put shadows on objects in c# windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a top navigation bar which is a panel. I set the BackColor of it to white. And I want it to cast a shadow so that it would be less pale though it would look simple and minimal. However, I do not know how do I do that other than putting borders to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop shadow in Winforms Controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463519/drop-shadow-in-winforms-controls)

Comment: It is possible this is impossible. Or at least way harder then it has any right to be. Windows Forms is over **2 decades** old, and has many issues doing things that in our day and age should be considered "normal". | In something modern like WPF it would propably be easy. But in wifnroms it will be somehwat hacky at least.

Comment: The power of winforms (and most of its underlying win32 apis) is that you can spend your time writing an interface in a uniform UI. All programs that were worth anything were done like this, although you can hack anything and winforms is no exception, you will be fighting a losing battle to make it look like a polished modern app. I would suggest learning a different UI like wpf, or UWP if you want that overall polished modern look, and not waste your effort push stuff up hill